# Cannot add property user, object is not extensible! Why the auth can't use username and password?

Tags: node.js, authentication, request

When I use an auth object that is deepFreeze like {"username":username,"password":password}, I am annoyed that it wants to convert to {"user":username,"pass":password}!

I see that in https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/request.js#L370 . But why can't I use which one or create a new object assignment?
I did not want to pass the auth incorrectly modified, but it is correct, but because I can't add the set user pass and report an error, this is very troublesome for me.

Comment: Could you please expand and rewrite your question? I can't understand the context or the issue. You would be more likely to receive an answer if you make your question clearer and/or include the code you're having the issue with.

Answer (score 0):

A frozen object can no longer be changed; freezing an object prevents new properties from being added to it, existing properties from being removed, prevents changing the enumerability, configurability, or writability of existing properties, and prevents the values of existing properties from being changed. In addition, freezing an object also prevents its prototype from being changed. freeze returns the same object that was passed in.

If someone in the program gives you frozen data you have to make a copy of it and edit it as desired and pass it on to other functions and Don't use a freezer when you have to change objects in your program. .